Can Stack Exchange have a direct interface to push code from GitHub?
I would like to see this feature implemented—an interface to push code from GitHub—as I keep having to copy paste code between Stack Exchange and GitHub.
I know that GitHub has its own discussion forum, but I often do not find answers to my questions there compared to Stack Exchange and would prefer this feature being implemented.

I don't understand why "code from github" would be relevant to any Stack Exchange network site other than Stack Overflow.

That sounds like an extremely bad idea. Here is why:

this feature would only benefit sites like Stack Overflow and none of the other sites in the SE network.
the license of the code on GitHub might not allow verbatim copying.
it will most likely break the Minimal Reproducible Example requirement for code in questions (or answers for that matter)
I doubt if more than 1% of the content posted would even contain exact copies of full GitHub code files.

The feature already exist. Click "Copy Raw File" in the GitHub UI to get a copy on the clipboard, paste the content of the clipboard in a Stack Exchange post.



Please don't use it.
